# cx_Freeze fails to include Cython .pyx module

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, cx-freeze

I have a Python application to which I recently added a Cython module. Running it from script with pyximport works fine, but I also need an executable version which I build with cx_Freeze.

Trouble is, trying to build it gives me an executable that raises ImportError trying to import the .pyx module.

I modified my `setup.py` like so to see if I could get it to compile the .pyx first so that cx_Freeze could successfully pack it:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
from Cython.Build import cythonize


setup(name='projectname',
      version='0.0',
      description=' ',
      options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame","fx"]},'build_ext': {'compiler': 'mingw32'}},
      ext_modules=cythonize("fx.pyx"),
      executables=[Executable('main.py',targetName="myproject.exe",base = "Win32GUI")],
      requires=['pygcurse','pyperclip','rsa','dill','numpy']
      )
```

... but then all that gives me is `No module named fx` within cx_Freeze at build-time instead.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to have two separate calls to `setup()`; one to build `fx.pyx` with Cython, then one to pack the exe with cx_Freeze. Here's the modified `setup.py`:

```
from cx_Freeze import Executable
from cx_Freeze import setup as cx_setup
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(options={'build_ext': {'compiler': 'mingw32'}},
      ext_modules=cythonize("fx.pyx"))

cx_setup(name='myproject',
      version='0.0',
      description='',
      options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame","fx"]}},
      executables=[Executable('main.py',targetName="myproject.exe",base = "Win32GUI")],
      requires=['pygcurse','pyperclip','rsa','dill','numpy']
      )
```

Comment: Just for informations, in order to make it works, you must type "python setup-cython.py build_ext --inplace" and then "python setup-cython.py build"