# ImportError When Using cx_Freeze On a Script The Includes ffpyplayer

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, cx-freeze

I successfully froze a Python 3.6 script with cx_Freeze v5.1.1.  Then I added a new capability to the script by adding MediaPlayer from the ffpyplayer package and the script works perfectly. But when I freeze the new script, I receive an error *"from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."*

The import statement in my application script is

`from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer`

From other posts, I have tried adding both `ffpyplayer` and `ffpyplayer.player` to the `packages` statement in the cx_Freeze `setup.py` script (in separate attempts) to fix the problem.  I also tried adding `player.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` to the `include` statement in setup.py, but I still got the same error message.

cx_Freeze copied all ffpyplayer files from `site-packages` into the `exe.win-amd64-3.6\lib\ffpyplayer` except the `__pycache__` folder containing `__init__.cpython-36.pyc`.  However, manually adding this folder to `exe.win-amd64-3.6\lib\ffpyplayer\` and to `exe.win-amd64-3.6\lib\ffpyplayer\player\`did not fix the issue (same error message).

Here is a minimal version of the setup.py file that cx_Freeze uses:

```py
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

d = "C:\\Users\\Slalo_000\\Dropbox\\Python36Scripts\\AddtoBuild\\"
exe=Executable(script="VSWv300.py", base = "Win32GUI", icon = d + "VSWiconLarge.ico")
includes=[]

excludes=[]
packages=["numpy", "cv2", "ffpyplayer"]
setup(
     version = "2.0.0.0",
     description = "appName",
     author = "me",
     author_email = "",
     name = "appName",
     options ={'build_exe'{'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includes}},
     executables = [exe]
     )
```

EDIT:  The full error message traceback is:

```
File “C:\Users\slalo_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py”, line 14, in run module.run()
File “C:\Users\slalo_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py”, line 26, in run exec(code, m.__dict__
File “VSWv300.py”, line 20, in <module> 
File “C:\Users\slalo_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\player\__init__.py”, line 10, in <module> from ffpyplayer.player.player import MediaPlayer
ImportError:DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at [cx_Freeze fails to include Cython .pyx module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31734230/8516269)?

Comment: Please also note that a `:` seems to be missing from your minimal setup script after `options ={'build_exe'`

Comment: I have never used distutils and am still finding my way around Python (after not programming for 30 years).  I read that setuptools simplifies packaging python scripts and uses distutils in the background. Can I package the script with setuptools and then freeze it with cx_Freeze?

Comment: I don't know, I never tried what you described. For sure, cx_Freeze overloads distutils, so one need to be careful when one uses both the standard distutils and cx_Freeze's overloaded one, as described in the accepted answer of the post I linked in my above above.

Comment: My guess is that cx_Freeze does not include dependencies or DLLs required by MediaPlayer. Could you please add the full traceback of the error you get to your post (as text)?

Comment: cx_Freeze added two DLLs to the player folder: (1) python36.dll` and (2) `VCRUNTIME140.dll`.  Also, as you suggested, I added the full error message traceback to the body of the post.